# Не работает цикл на foreach для removechatuser

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Приветствую всех посетителей данной темы.
Решил сделать кик из бесед с помощью цикла,а именно - с помощью цикла foreach.

```
if (mb_substr($message,0,5) == '?kick'){ 
$checkfromiduser = R::findOne('users', 'user_id = ?', [$id]);
$checkdostyp = $checkfromiduser->dostyp;
$cyclekick = [2000000034,2000000033,2000000035];
if ($checkdostyp >= 4) { 
    
    $kick_id = mb_substr($message ,6); 
    $kick_id = explode("|", mb_substr($kick_id, 3))[0];

    if($kick_id == ""){
        $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Вы забыли указать аргумент");
    } elseif(in_array($kick_id, $is_admin)) {
       $vk->sendMessage($peer_id,"Вы не можете исключить системного администратора");
    } else {

        $userInfo = $vk->request("users.get", ["user_ids" => $kick_id]);
        $first_name = $userInfo[0]['first_name']; // Имя исключаемого пользователя 
        $last_name = $userInfo[0]['last_name'];
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $userInfosecond = $vk->request("users.get",["user_ids" => $id]); 
        $firstsecond_name = $userInfosecond[0]['first_name'];
        $lastsecond_name = $userInfosecond[0]['last_name'];
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        $chat_data = $vk->request('messages.getConversationsById', ['peer_ids' => $peer_id, 'extended' => 0]);
        $title = $chat_data['items'][0]['chat_settings']['title'];
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $idc = implode(" ", $args);
        $clrdostyp = R::Findone('users', 'user_id = ?' [$kick_id]);
        foreach ($cyclekick as $chat_id => $cyclekicked) {
          $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $cyclekicked, 'member_id' => $kick_id]);
          $vk->sendMessage($cyclekicked, "@id$kick_id ($first_name $last_name)\n✅Удален из беседы по запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc ");
        }
        
        $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "@id$kick_id ($first_name $last_name)\n✅Удален из беседы по запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc ");
        $vk->sendMessage($log, "✅Из беседы: $peer_id \nНазвание: $title\nБыл удален @id$kick_id($first_name $last_name)\nПо запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc");
        
    }
} else {
    $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Данная команда доступна с 4 уровня доступа. У вас: $checkdostyp");

 }
}
```

Суть в том,что кик не работает с помощью такого метода,но сообщения в указанные беседы с помощью цикла отправляет на ура

```
foreach ($cyclekick as $chat_id => $cyclekicked) {
      $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $cyclekicked, 'member_id' => $kick_id]);
      $vk->sendMessage($cyclekicked, "@id$kick_id ($first_name $last_name)\n✅Удален из беседы по запросу $firstsecond_name $lastsecond_name\nПричина: $idc ");
    }
```

Прошу разъяснить как можно сделать,чтобы оно заработало.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всех.
Пересмотрел документацию,все оказалось проще простого.
Когда я указывал айди бесед из которых нужно кикнуть пользователя - я указывал неверно айди,в формате 20000000019,а нужно было в формате $confs = [34,35,33];

```
 if($message == "?testkick") {
   $confs = [34,35,33];
   $kick_id = 608723470;
  foreach($confs as $confs) {
    
    $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', array('chat_id' => $confs, 'member_id' => $kick_id));
    $why= $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $confs, 'member_id' => $kick_id]);
    $why = $why['error'];
    $why = $why['error_code'];
    $vk->SendMessage($peer_id,"$why $confs $kick_id");
  }
 }
```

Как у меня получилось - кикнуло из всех вышеуказанных бесед.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте во время вызова `messages.removeChatUser` указать ещё и параметр `user_id` - задайте ему точно такое же значение, что и `member_id`

```
$vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $cyclekicked, 'member_id' => $kick_id, 'user_id' => $kick_id]);
```

Насколько я знаю, `user_id` - обязательный параметр

Comment: Привет,спасибо за подсказку,вероятно всего проблема в том,что через функцию не будет работать,еще до сих пор не могу сделать(